# Получение данных с OPC-сервера

Tags: python, python-2.x, opc

Подключение производится к серверу OPC(по локальной сети) через `OpenOPC`.

Проблема в том что через несколько запросов на получение данных, они перестают поступать и вылетает ошибка по `timeout`.

Пока заметил что помогает только перезапуск службы OPC-сервера. Но не на долго, проблема повторяется.

Кто сталкивался, как с этим бороться?

(DCOM не настраивался и пока не рассматривается, но если ничего не решится, придется через DCOM подключение организовывать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге выяснилось, что OPC-сервер принимает на опрос полученные запросы и если осуществить новый запрос, а данные не обновились к тому времени, то произойдет вылет по `timeout`. Для того чтоб этого избежать, необходимо в обязательном порядке убирать с опроса запрашиваемые теги. Единственным способом, который удалось найти и проверить, это добавлять группу или группы при опросе и после того как вы получили все данные, удалять группы. После этого OPC-сервер очистит из своего модуля опросы ваших тегов.

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же ситуация. Т.к. не было никаких сообщений об ошибке, я включил опцию "получать сообщение об ошибке": `include_error=True`. После этого обмен заработал без сбоев. Без этой опции вылетает по `timeout`.
Пример кода:

```
import OpenOPC
import time
opc = OpenOPC.client()
# узнаем список доступных серверов
server=opc.servers()
print server 
# выбираем третий из списка
server=server[2]  
print ("Connect to Server: " + server)
# подключемся к серверу
opc.connect(server)
# создаем список опрашиваемых регистров для прибора Owen MB110-8A
tagsValue=[];
tagsStatus=[];
for each in range(1,9):
    tagsValue.append(u'Node1.MB110-8A.Input'+str(each)+'.Value')  # регистры значений
    tagsStatus.append(u'Node1.MB110-8A.Input'+str(each)+'.Status') # регистры статуса
# инициализируем группы опроса
opc.read(tagsValue,group='value',update=1,include_error=True)
opc.read(tagsStatus,group='status',update=1,include_error=True)
# в тестовой программе я опрашивал регистры 100 раз
i=0
while i<100:
    #    считываем значения
    data=opc.read(group='value',update=1, include_error=True)
    statusList=opc.read(group='status',update=1, include_error=True)
    # парсим данные, форматируем и выводим в консоль
    j=0
    temp=list()
    messages=list()
    while j<(len(data)-0):
        adress,value,answ,clock,Message=data[j]
        adress,status,answ,clock,Message=statusList[j]
        #print status
        if (status==0):
            temp.append(value)
        else:
            temp.append(0);
        messages.append(Message)
        j+=1
    j=0
    text=''+clock+"-> "
    while j<len(temp):
       text+= ("{t}").format(t="%6.1f"%(temp[j]))#+messages[j]+"\n"
       j+=1
    print text
    i+=1
    time.sleep(3)
# отключаемся    
opc.close()
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, но к сожалению я уже не смогу проверить его_)